# Converting Multilabel dataset into Single Label?

Tags: machine-learning, weka, data-mining, rapidminer, text-classification

i am working on single label text categrorization with a dataset of reuter-21578 however the dataset is multi-label by default. Many researchers removed multilabel instances from thi dataset and their number of instances in reuters categories is quite different than mine. How can i remove all the instance that belongs to more than one category in a dataset ? Can i use weka or Rapidminer for this purpose to identify multilabel instances in a dataset ?

**Example:**

```
    Input Dataset = {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10}
    Labels = {acq, earn, grain , corn}


    Classification Results = 

    x1, x2, x3 = acq
    x4, x5 = earn
    x6, x7, x8 = grain
    x9 = grain, corn
    x10 = grain, acq

    Output Dataset (what i want) = 
    output dataset = {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8}
    output labels = {acq, earn, grain, corn}

    Classification Results = 

    x1, x2, x3 = acq
    x4, x5 = earn
    x6, x7, x8 = grain

    **OR**
    {This is what i assume i have achieved with PolynomiaByBinomial Operator }
    output dataset = {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10}
    output labels = {acq, earn, grain, corn}
    Classification Results = 

    x1, x2, x3 = acq
    x4, x5 = earn
    x6, x7, x8, x9, x10 = grain
    x9 = grain
    x10 = grain
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Generally it will be possible to use RapidMiner (which includes Weka by the way) but I don't quite understand the question enough to give a precise answer. Could you give an example?

Comment: @awchisholm i have a dataset reuters-21578, It is a multi-label dataset by default where some documents may belong to more than one category like documents in category "grain" and "corn" etc. I want to convert this multi-label dataset into single label dataset by removing all documents that belongs to more than one category.

Comment: So you mean you have multiple columns. Each column is a possible label in its own right. Do you want to remove all but one of the label columns and keep all the rows?

Comment: @awchisholm it looks like i did not ask the question properly which confused the readers, I apologize for this. I searched on alot of things since yesterday and came to conclusion that all i have to do is to do "problem transformation using binary relevance (or any other way)" to transform my multi-label data set into single label. I am doing it by "Polynomial By Binomial" operator in rapid miner.I also reached to this question "http://rapid-i.com/rapidforum/index.php?topic=2505.0" on rapidminer forum which is exactly what i wanted to achieve. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to break the dataset into binary problems. If for example you have the datasets

```
text1: science
text2: sports, politics
```

Break the dataset into 3 datasets:

```
dataset1 (science): text1:true, text2:false
dataset2 (sports): text2:false, text2:true
dataset3 (science): text1:false, text2:true
```

Create 3 binary classifiers, one for each class, use the corresponding datasets to train them, and combine the results.